# physics collision help

Tags: modeling, animation

I have a bowl full of cubes, and they all have rigid body physics on them set to active. I am trying to make another cube rotate up from under the ones above it, but when I apply passive or active rigid body physics to it, nothing happens. The cube will animate to the spot I want, but will go through the other cubes. I want to make it push its way up and the other cubes react to it and move out of the way. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hmm… remember having to toy with this one… try “animated”

Comment: You need to explain more than just using one word in quotes. The 7x7 cube is animated coming up from under the pile of 3x3 cubes.

Comment: Oh, you mean the animated checkbox in the rigid body settings for the 7x7 cube that is coming up?

Comment: could you please share your file? (only keep several rubik's cube so that your file is not too heavy) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @adlowe07 yes, that property. Sorry.

Comment: @moonboots  here is how it turned out. Thanks. https://youtu.be/_UQNPK1ixJY

Comment: good result!  ;)